# How to skip adding newline in data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file

I have the code below to merge 2 dataframs columns in one dataframe :
where the first one contains predicted text
And for the other part contains ground truth value

```
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

def load_jsonl(text_path):
    return pd.read_json(
                         path_or_buf = text_path,
                         lines=True
                        )

# get the path/directory
working_dir = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Class_B/"

df = load_jsonl(f'{working_dir}labels.jsonl')

# Using readlines()
file1 = open(f'{working_dir}3rd_col.txt', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()

col_3rd = pd.DataFrame(Lines, columns=['Ground_truth'])

result = pd.concat([df, col_3rd ], axis=1)
import json
reddit = result.to_dict(orient= "records")
print(type(reddit) , len(reddit))
with open(f"{working_dir}Class_B.jsonl","w") as f:
    for line in reddit:
        f.write(json.dumps(line,ensure_ascii=False) + "\n")
```

the input files in json line format
`labels.jsonl`

```
{"image_name": "1.JPG", "text": "Flattery is words of kindness for a"}
{"image_name": "2.JPG", "text": "potential favor."}
```

The third column name `3rd_col.txt`

```
Flattery is words of kindness for a 
potential favor.
```

I got the resulting file as below `Class_B.jsonl`:

```
{"image_name": "1.JPG", "text": "Flattery is words of kindness for a", "Ground_truth": "Flattery is words of kindness for a \n"}
{"image_name": "2.JPG", "text": "potential favor.", "Ground_truth": "potential favor.  \n"}
```

The expacted reults : Should look without `\n`

```
{"image_name": "1.JPG", "text": "Flattery is words of kindness for a", "Ground_truth": "Flattery is words of kindness for a"}
{"image_name": "2.JPG", "text": "potential favor.", "Ground_truth": "potential favor."}
```

Comment: `lines =  file1.read().splitlines()` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for [@dkruit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13769079/dkruit) answer

```
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

def load_jsonl(text_path):
    return pd.read_json(
                         path_or_buf = text_path,
                         lines=True
                        )

# get the path/directory
working_dir = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Class_B/"

df = load_jsonl(f'{working_dir}labels.jsonl')

# Using readlines()
file1 = open(f'{working_dir}3rd_col.txt', 'r')
Lines = file1.read().splitlines()

col_3rd = pd.DataFrame(Lines, columns=['Ground_truth'])

result = pd.concat([df, col_3rd ], axis=1)
import json
reddit = result.to_dict(orient= "records")

with open(f"{working_dir}Class_B.jsonl","w") as f:
    for line in reddit:
        f.write(json.dumps(line,ensure_ascii=False) + "\n")
```